# When searching for pdf's get link to file and not dispform?id=x

Tags: search, search-results

I understand that I have to install adobe ifilter if I want to be able to search through the content of PDF files but I don't need that. I have a custom content type for files stored in the library where the PDF's are (among other file types) and I only need to be able to search for the meta data I have set up. I added PDF file extension in search service settings as recommended, reset index and new full crawl but no luck.

Is adobe ifilter really necessary when I do only want to be able to search on meta data tags and not what's in the actual file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For Document Library items, the link returned in the search results will be the link to the file.  Metadata will be considered in determining relevancy.

If you want to show a link to the Property Display form, then you will want to either customize the output of your results page or use a standard list and attach your PDF to a list item.